# How to structure AngularJS-Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

What should be the file structure of an **Angularjs + Rails** project. I am doing the angular part(never work with rails before) in this project. Previously i combined php frameworks(ci/laravel) with angular and the file structure was like following.

```
ngProjectFolder
-scripts
-views
-index.html
-backend(ci/laravel project folder)
--application
--index.php
```

I also worked on such file structure where angular files are put into php frameworks assets and view folders. e.g.

```
phpProjectFolder (ci/laravel)
-assets
--js
---angularjs controller and other js files
--css
-controller(php)
-model(php)
-view
--angular view files
```

None of these file structure are exact(unnecessary folder are not shown here). I just wanted show an overview.

**I will use Angular routing system.**

Which file structure should i use and why? Is there any security issues?
Need some advice. 
thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/sectore/CafeTownsend-Angular-Rails

Comment: There are various options.Dump the Angular Project in Rails App/assets/JAvascript folder.or dump in Public folder

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the PHP project you mentioned, you can use:

```
RailsProjectFolder
-app
--assets
---javascript
----angularjs
```